# Python List in a For Loop

Tags: python, string, list, loops

I am new to Python and had a question about updating a list using a for loop. Here is my code:

```
urls = ['http://www.city-data.com/city/javascript:l("Abbott");' , 'http://www.city-data.com/city/javascript:l("Abernathy");' ,

'http://www.city-data.com/city/Abilene-Texas.html' ,'http://www.city-data.com/city/javascript:l("Abram-Perezville");' ,  

'http://www.city-data.com/city/javascript:l("Ackerly");' , 'http://www.city-data.com/city/javascript:l("Adamsville");', 

'http://www.city-data.com/city/Addison-Texas.html']

for url in urls:
    if "javascript" in url:
        print url
        url = url.replace('javascript:l("','').replace('");','-Texas.html')
        print url

for url in urls:
    if "javascript" in url:
        url = url.replace('javascript:l("','').replace('");','-Texas.html')
print "\n"  
print urls
```

I used the first for loop to check if the syntax was correct, and it worked fine. But the second for loop is the code I want to use, but it's not working properly. How would I go about globally updating the list with the second for loop so I can print or store the updated list outside of the for loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can update the list items using their index:

```
for i, url in enumerate(urls):
    if "javascript" in url:
        urls[i] = url.replace('javascript:l("','').replace('");','-Texas.html')
```

Another alternative is to use a list comprehension:

```
def my_replace(s):
    return s.replace('javascript:l("','').replace('");','-Texas.html')

urls[:] = [my_replace(url) if "javascript" in url else url for url in urls]
```

Here `urls[:]` means replace all the items of `urls` list with the new list created by the list comprehension.

The reason why your code didn't worked is that you're assigning the variable `url` to something else, and changing one of the reference of an object to point to something else doesn't affect the other references. So, your code is equivalent to:

```
>>> lis = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
>>> url = lis[0]                   #create new reference to 'aa'
>>> url = lis[0].replace('a', 'd') #now assign url to a new string that was returned by `lis[0].replace`
>>> url 
'dd'
>>> lis[0]
'aa'
```

Also note that `str.replace` always returns a new copy of string, it never changes the original string because strings are immutable in Python. In case `lis[0]` was a list and you performed any in-place operation on it using `.append`, `.extend` etc, then that would have affected the original list as well.

Comment: Thanks, I found this helpful too. I am newbie and came to SO to do some studying :-) In my study I think I found a slight error in your code. `return s.url.replace('javascript:l("','').replace('");','-Texas.html')` -- should be -- `return s.replace('javascript:l("','').replace('");','-Texas.html')`

Comment: @Darren Nice catch, fixed that. :-)

Comment: is `urls[:]` needed when replacing with list comprehension? Doesn't it return a new list?

Comment: @JimmyKane `urls[:]` means replace all the items of `urls` list with the items from iterable on the RHS. This is different than a simple `urls = [...]`. If he had something like `a = b = [1, 2, 3]`, and then we used `b[:] = [x**2 for x in b]`, then this will affect both `a` and `b`.